# Convert PNG32s to PNG8s and with matted indexed transparency

Tags: imagemagick

We have a range of product images that have been clear cut by our graphic designers and have been saved as PNG32s with transparent backgrounds. We need to convert these to PNG8 as they are uploaded to the website (using ImageMagick) so the files are nice and small.

The images are displayed at various positions over a grey gradient background so they need to retain their transparency.

Because the PNG8s will have indexed transparency, we want to matte just the semi-transparent anti-aliased edge pixels with the average grey of the gradient.

What's the nicest way of doing this im ImageMagic? I've found lots of cool ways of transforming/removing/flattening the alpha channel but it doesn't help much with the task of targeting and matting only semi-transparent pixels. Anyone done this before?